# Could you help me understand a pun?

Tags: traduction, jeux-de-mots

I am translating a text and the whole idea is:

A student is late for his class and he starts making up a story about a werewolf (loup-garou) chasing him and when the teacher gets bored he shouts, imitating the sound of a wolf:"Toi, la prochaine fois, je ne te louperai pas!"

Which I think should be a joke because un loup is a wolf, how would you translate it?

Also could you please explain there is such a phrase: J'ai eu une de ces trouilles, why does he use this instead of simply saying J'ai eu la trouille , what's the difference in translation?

Thanks

Comment: Just one question per post, please. And the first one isn't really on topic — looks like you understand the pun, but translating it is more an exercise in English ingenuity than in knowing anything about French. But just for fun: if he met a werewolf, the teacher could say, "And *where* was this wolf?" or "My patience is *wearing* thin!" or "Next time we'll see who *wears* the pants!" Or if you change the mythical beast for a dragon: "Just watch out if I catch you draggin' your feet again!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also could you please explain there is such a phrase: J'ai eu une de
>   ces trouilles, why does he use this instead of simply saying J'ai eu
>   la trouille , what's the difference in translation?

The un/une used in this context is for adding a strong emotion related to the event. Other exemples would be; [ref](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3399)

- J'avais **un** de ces mal de tête.
- J'ai hâte d'arriver au restaurant; j'ai **une** de ces faims!

Dans la langue courante, plus particulièrement dans les phrases exclamatives, on fait parfois précéder un nom de la construction **un de ces** ou **une de ces** pour indiquer une grande intensité. Généralement, on met ce nom au pluriel, et ce, même s'il n'est pas dénombrable.

> he shouts, imitating the sound of a wolf:"Toi, la prochaine fois, je
>   ne te louperai pas!"

For that part it's a good pun your teacher did IMO, as it's the verb *louper*, which means the next time he will not get away. It's a clear warning to the student and at the same time he used a verb that sounded like *loup*.